# Making an image as a bullet in each new line in textview

Tags: swift, textview, nstextattachment, bulletedlist

I'm trying to make sth similar to bullet list in TextView but instead of bullets I have an image. The problem is that when I create the new line by normal "`\n`   " sign the space before the image in the line is editable.
And I want to make that image to be always first sign in line
So I'm asking about:

1. bullets points
2. instead of bullets an image
3. u can't pass text before a bullet

   ```
   private var stringWithNewPointersInside = NSMutableAttributedString()
   private var pointerAsTextValue = NSAttributedString()
   private var image = UIImage()
   private var imageView = UIImageView()

   private let pointer = NSTextAttachment()


   public func checkList(noteTextValue: NSAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
       stringWithNewPointersInside = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: noteTextValue)
       stringWithNewPointersInside.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))

       pointer.image = createImage(name: EMPTY_TICK_IMAGE, newSize: CGSize(width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
       pointerAsTextValue = NSAttributedString(attachment: pointer)
       stringWithNewPointersInside.append(pointerAsTextValue)
       stringWithNewPointersInside.append(NSAttributedString(string: "   "))
       return stringWithNewPointersInside
   }


   private func createImage(name: String, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage{
       var newImage = UIImage(named: name)!
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
       newImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
       newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       return newImage
   }
   ```

Comment: Please don't include your source code as an image.